# Toshiba Libretto 50ct replacement display

Tags: laptop, lcd-display

Is there a cost effective new display panel that could fit to retro Toshiba Libretto 50ct?
Mine is broken and panels are hard to find. Maybe little bigger like in Libretto 70ct could fit too with new bezel or mod?
Thank you.

Comment: Your best bet might be to search for a broken Libretto with a good display.  Not a very common model though, so it may take some time to find one.  Could a new display be adapted to the Libretto?  Of course, given enough time and effort.  But only you can decide how much effort and money is worthwhile.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, been looking several years for now, looks like impossible to find on local markets. Customs and import duty cancels from buying over seas.

Comment: Are you asking what model of screen would be compatible or where to get one cheaply? I think the former would be okay, but the latter is more of a shopping question which are generally frowned upon. As phrased now, it’s vague enough to be interpreted either way.

Comment: Sorry about that. Asking where to get any compatible display in a cost effective manner.